# What is the part of speech of the word " fancy" in the following content?

Tags: conversational-deletion

Recently,i saw a sort of propoganda/advertisement about body-building on a random chap's instagram.

1.OP:"Fancy losing inches off your waist?Flattening your tummy?Fancy winning a waist trainer that will do all that for FREE??! Simply like this post and FOLLOW blablablablabla

What part of speech does the "fancy" function as in the sentence above?It's an adjective or what?

Comment: I *should* ask you to include your research and what you think, but: It's a verb.

Answer (score 1):

"*Fancy*" here is a *verb*.

It is acceptable in spoken English to start a question with the main verb.  The meaning of

> Fancy losing inches off your waist?

is

> *Do you* fancy losing inches off your waist?

Comment: Oxford definitions is mostly dedicated to British English ? What do you think ? I mean If Americans also use it like your answer, start a question with main verb ?

Comment: I don't think it's my place to review dictionaries.  And I don't think it's limited to Americans as far as starting a question with the main verb. I'll look for examples in English literature...

Comment: A quick glance pointed me to this question/answer: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66972/why-is-there-omission-of-subject-in-sentences-like-thought-youd-never-ask/66994#66994 .  I'm sure I'll find more.